# Java equivalent of Ruby's String.unpack for "q*"

Tags: java, ruby

In Java, I'm trying to decode an integer written by the following ruby code:

```
def int_to_hex_string(i)
  [i].pack('q').reverse
end
```

For the number 42, the resulting string will be `"\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00*"`.

The following Ruby code will reverse the process:

```
def hex_string_to_int(s)
  s.reverse.unpack('q*').first
end
```

How can I emulate this last method in Java?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Update: the simplest way is using java.math.BigInteger:

```
return new BigInteger(bytes).intValue();
```

Or, if one really wants to implement it oneself:

```
public static int unpackInteger(byte[] bytes) {
    int sum = 0;
    int mul = 1;

    for (int i=bytes.length-1; i >= 0; i--) {
        sum += (mul * (bytes[i] & 0xff));
        mul <<= 8;
    }
    return sum;
}
```